# Attribute routing with "json" string in url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have hard time to make working attribute routing for urls ending with `.json`. It is working for `GET` requests and not working with `POST` requests. Not sure what is wrong.

I have 2 controllers. In one controller I have:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("stock.json")]
public HttpResponseMessage Stocks(int? limit = null, int? offset = null)
```

In another controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("orders.json")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddOrder([FromBody]OrderRest order)
```

In `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Json" path="*.json" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

First works perfectly fine, the second does not. As soos as I change `POST` to `GET` it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very silly. In config I have configured it only for `verb="GET"`. Just changed to `verb="GET,POST,PUT"`.